# What is `__config__()` in a python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I was coding with SQLalchemy and FastAPI when came across this error, but I think it's just some canonical Python that I'm not understanding.

In a Python class, what is the `__config__` method for?

```py
class MyClass:

    def __config__(self):
        ...
```

For context, I was creating some wrappers for SQLalchemy, like

```py
class SQLMixins:
    def save(self, session):
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(self)

  
class HouseBase(SQLModel, SQLMixins):
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

When I tried to run this, it got this error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
type object 'SQLMixins' has no attribute '__config__'
  File "/home/jokea/code/repeople-demo/repeople/models/house.py", line 33, in <module>
    class HouseBase(SQLModel, SQLMixins):
```

I added in a simple

```py
    def __config__(self):
        pass
```

to my `SQLMixins` class, and it started working properly.

I understand that classes have built-ins like `__init__`, `__repr__`, etc, but why what is `__config__` for, and why would its omission cause python to complain like that?

Comment: `__config__` in this case at least, comes from pydantic - see https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/ and https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/

Comment: also note that pydantic has defined it as an attribute `__config__`, not a method `__config__()`